# r - How to find value with condition

Tags: r

```
Name    Score    Time
A       5        1/1
B       4        1/1
A       7        2/1
A       5        3/1
C       4        5/1
A       10       10/1
...
```

How can i find the max value in after exact 3 times submit (max value of all times if submit<3times)
EX

```
Name    Score
A       7
B       4
C       4
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'Name', `filter` the rows where the `row_number()` is less than or equal to 3 and then get the `max` of 'Score'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    filter(row_number() <=3) %>% 
    summarise(Score = max(Score))
# A tibble: 3 × 2
#   Name Score
#  <chr> <int>
#1     A     7
#2     B     4
#3     C     4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)